# yup object type in typescript for an object that has a typed field as array of an object

Tags: typescript, forms, validation, next.js, yup

I'm trying to enforce the yup schema object to be implemented to the interfaces, in the future
if any field has been added to the Model(interface) has to be validated by yup schema, otherwise ther will be type error,
but "Product" interface has an array field "attributes" typed as "Attribute[]"

here are the interfaces:

```
export interface Attribute {
  key: string
  value: string
}

export interface Product {
  id: string
  productName: string
  productDes: string
  barcode: string
  warehouseType: string
  brand: string
  type: string
  attributes: Attribute[]
}
```

and here is the yup schema object

```
export const productSchema : yup.SchemaOf<Product>  = yup.object().shape({
  id: yup
    .string()
    .min(9, obj => showErrors('id', obj.value.length, obj.min))
    .required(),
  productName: yup
    .string()
    .min(9, obj => showErrors('productName', obj.value.length, obj.min))
    .required(),
  productDes: yup
    .string()
    .min(3, obj => showErrors('productDes', obj.value.length, obj.min))
    .required(),
  barcode: yup
    .string()
    .min(3, obj => showErrors('barcode', obj.value.length, obj.min))
    .required(),
  warehouseType: yup
    .string()
    .min(3, obj => showErrors('warehouseType', obj.value.length, obj.min))
    .required(),
  brand: yup
    .string()
    .min(3, obj => showErrors('brand', obj.value.length, obj.min))
    .required(),
  attributes: yup
    .array<Attribute>()
    .required()
})

type ProductSchemaType = yup.InferType<typeof productSchema>
```

when I hover on th "ProductSchemaType" I'm getting this

```
type ProductSchemaType = {
    id: string;
    productName: string;
    productDes: string;
    barcode: string;
    warehouseType: string;
    brand: string;
    type: string;
    attributes: AssertsShape<{
        key: yup.BaseSchema<Maybe<string>, AnyObject, string>;
        value: yup.BaseSchema<...>;
    }>[] | undefined;
}
```

but I'm expecting to get the "Product" interface

I tried to remove the the type from the "productSchema" then get this one

```
type ProductSchemaType = {
    [x: string]: never;
    id: string;
    productName: string;
    productDes: string;
    barcode: string;
    warehouseType: string;
    brand: string;
    attributes: any[];
}
```

when hovering on the "ProductSchemaType", the "attributes" field has "any[]", but this breaks my prupose of strongly typing,

so how to type the "attributes" field in the "productSchema" to get its type from "ProductSchemaType" as Product interface?

Comment: You can't just do `yup.array<Attribute>()`. You need to make the schema for the Attribute interface, too.

Comment: @vera. I tried this one 
`const attributeSchema: yup.SchemaOf<Attribute> = yup.object().shape({
  key: yup.string().required(),
  value: yup.string().required()
}).required()
`
and put it in the "productSchema" like this 
`attributes: yup.array(attributeSchema).min(1).required()
`
 but it still doesn't work,
TS says this "Property 'type' is missing in type '..... attributes: OptionalArraySchema<...>' but required in type '.... attributes: ArraySchema<...>;' "

Comment: and when hovering over the "ProductSchemaType" I got the type of the "attributes" field like this `attributes: AssertsShape<{
        key: yup.BaseSchema<Maybe<string>, AnyObject, string>;
        value: yup.BaseSchema<...>;
    }>[] | undefined;`
maybe the " | undefined" type makes the trouble.